# Not setting document.domain on channel file

Tags: facebook, cross-domain, channel

Setting the document.domain in a Facebook app, but not in the channel file seemed to not cause issues before the July 2012 code cleanup. But after, cross-domain security errors will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a question, but when I searched the issue, I didn't find anything related and thought it important to make a note of it in case someone else has this problem too.